# Is this port of Prototype to JQuery correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

We have code that will run if the user is idle for a certain amount of time. 
(doStuff resets a countdown)

Existing code in Prototype:

```
Event.observe(window, 'mousemove', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(window, 'scroll', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(window, 'click', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(window, 'focus', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(window, 'blur', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(window, 'keypress', function() { doStuff(); });

Event.observe(document, 'mousemove', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(document, 'scroll', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(document, 'click', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(document, 'focus', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(document, 'blur', function() { doStuff(); });
Event.observe(document, 'keypress', function() { doStuff(); });
```

I am looking to replace it with this JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).bind("mousemove scroll click focus blur keypress", doStuff);
 });
```

It checks out when I test it, but can anyone confirm I don't have to do the document/window check, or that I didn't overlook anything else?  Thanks.

Comment: As for answer, i don't know, but if you can stack all the binds to one `bind` command... it's pretty awesome :]

Comment: Yeah it appears to function correctly, which makes me happy.

Comment: I noticed focus and blur don't do call the function when I tab around the form, not sure if that even worked in the old way...

Comment: Almost certainly not, focus and blur don't bubble, you have to observe them on the individual elements. You can either do that once with a selector, or if you're adding/removing input elements jQuery's `live` method may help: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Close, this is a complete port (added `window`) and the Document ready test isn't needed:

```
 $([document, window]).bind("mousemove scroll click focus blur keypress", doStuff);
```

You can pass an array to the jQuery function so what you set up applies to more than one item. In this case, you already have references to `window` and `document`. This is how you can do it in one call.

However, I don't think all the original Prototype code was needed. For instance, `focus` and `blur` dont' apply to the `document` and `click`, `mousemove` and `keypress` isn't needed on the `window`.

This might be more what you want:

```
$(window).bind("focus blur scroll", doStuff);
$(document).bind("click mousemove keypress scroll", doStuff);
```

*DOM Ready not needed*: The DOM ready test is not needed because you already have access to `document` and `window` immediately. Waiting for DOM ready is needless.

Comment: @blu just updated my answer with a little more detail. And I realized that `$(document).ready` was not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  It works, I like it, question closed.

Answer (score 1):

That Prototype code is...non-optimal to say the least, and not for any reason related to Prototype.

Your rewrite looks fine other than that you've dropped `window`. If not hooking the events on `window` is valid in jQuery, it's valid in Prototype.

A similar rewrite in Prototype making similar assumptions (but including `window`):

```
$w('mousemove scroll click focus blur keypress').each(function(evtname) {
    document.observe(evtname, doStuff);
    Event.observe(window, evtname, doStuff);
});
```

...and I wouldn't be surprised to find that even that's more verbose than it actually needs to be.